# Find Increment # of X

Tags: math, iteration, increment

I have a number X can range between 1 to N

lets assume X = 5

I need to find out 3 set of numbers

```
1st Set of Numbers: 1,4
2nd Set of Numbers: 2,5
3rd Set of Numbers: 3
```

and now if X = 12 then

lets assume X = 5

I need to find out 10 set of numbers

```
1st Set of Numbers: 1,4,7,10
2nd Set of Numbers: 2,5,8
3rd Set of Numbers: 3,6,9
```

So the question is how can I find out those 3 sets of numbers when the X is unknown, what is the equation? or do I have to iterate the numbers?

I assume it has to do with division also rounding???

Comment: You mean N = 12 or = 5?

Comment: If X = 12 in your second example and not 5 wouldn't 11 be in your second set of numbers ? If the difference between each number is 3 and the first set starts at 1 isn't this a simple problem or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

what is the actual value of X ? And I'm seeing 3 set of numbers here, not 10 set. So please, before posting please check your question again.

From given 2 outputs, it seems(as your problem isn't clear) output will always consists of 3 sets. 1st will start from 1, second one from 2 and 3rd one from 3. Difference between two neighboring number will be 3 in a set. You just have continue until X is reached. If this is the problem, it is too easy. Am I getting wrong anything ?